# How to filter an array of routes by permision?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of routes with permissions and an array with permissions of the current user, which is being checked, how to leave only those routes for which the array of permissions matches the array of permissions of the current user

```js
let routerArray = [
    { name: 'Main', permissions: [{ name: 'User' }, { name: 'Manager' }, { name: 'Admin' }] },
    { name: 'Home', permissions: [{ name: 'User' }, { name: 'Manager' }] },
    { name: 'Users', permissions: [{ name: 'User' }] }
];

let currentPermissions = [
    { name: 'User' },
    { name: 'Manager' }
];
```

my attempt

```js
function routerFilter(currentPermissions, routes) {
    return routes.filter(router => {
        return router
            .permissions
            .every(permission => permission.name.includes(currentPermissions));
    });
}
console.log(routerFilter(currentPermissions, routerArray));
```

expected result

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Main",
        "permissions": [
            { "name": "User" },
            { "name": "Manager" },
            { "name": "Admin" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Home",
        "permissions": [
            { "name": "User" }, 
            { "name": "Manager" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I think you just need to change the check in every to `currentPermissions.map(({name}) => name).includes(permission.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```js
let routes = [
    {name: 'Main', permissions: [{name: 'User'}, {name: 'Manager'}, {name: 'Admin'}]},
    {name: 'Home', permissions: [{name: 'User'}, {name: 'Manager'}]},
    {name: 'Users', permissions: [{name: 'User'}]}
]

let currentPermissions = [
    {name: 'User'},
    {name: 'Manager'}
]

result = routes.filter(route =>
    currentPermissions.every(p =>
        route.permissions.some(rp => rp.name === p.name)))

console.log(result)
```

If used repeatedly, this can be optimized by precomputing Sets of permission names for each route:

```
function routerFilter(currentPermissions, routes) {
    routes.forEach(route => 
        route._permNames = route._permNames ?? new Set(route.permissions.map(p => p.name)))
    
    return routes.filter(route =>
        currentPermissions.every(p => route._permNames.has(p.name)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const routerArray = [
  {name: 'Main', permissions: [{name:'User'},{name: 'Manager'},{name:'Admin'}]},
  {name: 'Home', permissions: [{name:'User'},{name:'Manager'}]},
  {name: 'Users', permissions: [{name:'User'}]}
];
const currentPermissions = [
  {name: 'User'},
  {name: 'Manager'}
];

function routerFilter(currentPermissions, routes) {
  return routes.filter(({ permissions = [] }) => {
    // get router permissions set
    const permissionNames = permissions.map(({ name }) => name);
    const routerPermissions = new Set(permissionNames);
    // check if the set has all currentPermissions names
    return currentPermissions.every(({ name }) => routerPermissions.has(name))
  });
}
console.log(routerFilter(currentPermissions, routerArray));
```